# How to set up apache2 for react

Tags: apache, reactjs

I have react app running on apache2.

In my app, there are 3 pages: home, about, register

I have 3 route like this:

```
<Route path="/home" component={....} />
<Route path="/about" component={.....} />
<Route path="/register" component={....} />
```

So, app works perfectly, when I go to www.onlyexampleurl.com, app is loaded correctly. I can list in home, about, register fine.

But, problem is, when I go directly to www.onlyexampleurl.com/about i am getting 404 from apache, because app is download from root path '/'.

How can I fix it? When I put www.onlyexampleurl.com/about to browser I want load about page from my app, but I am gettint 404 from apache.

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 0):

You need to redirect all requests to your entry file (assume it's index.html). Put in `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.html [QSA,L]
```

This is standard solution for Single Page Apps.

Answer (score 0):

This is a late response to the question, but I though I'd share what worked.for me, in case anyone bumps into the same problem.

This is assuming Ubuntu OS, I have not been successful for Linux:

I've followed certain steps from this [post from Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/reactjs/comments/4e6lbt/getting_react_routing_to_work_with_apache2) and I can attest this works for making SPAs run in Apache web server with proper routing.

To quote:

1) In the `apache2.conf` located in `etc/apache2/` I turned `AllowOverride` to `All`. I also added Servername localhost in the file. (I somehow skipped this last sentence, but still it worked fine in the end)

```
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

2) In the `hosts.debian.tmpl` file found in `/etc/cloud/templates` I added `127.0.0.1 <yourdomain.com>` to the file where the other ips of the similiarity are.

```
127.0.0.1 yourdomain.com
```

3) I ran `sudo a2enmod rewrite`. Then I restarted the apache server via `service apache2 restart`. This turns on mod_rewrite.

Lastly inside of my project folder `/var/www/html` , along side my `index.html` file I created a `.htaccess` file and added in the following:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^.*$ / [L,QSA]
```

End quote

Assuming you've run `npm run build` and then copied all the contents inside the `build` folder to your public directory, this should work.

When I first started web dev, I wasn't really sure I made the VirtualHost config right, so what I usually did was first to make a dummy index.html with, say, Hello World example. When I've confirmed that I'm able to see Hello World in the browser (which means I got the VirtualHost config right), I dump the contents of the `build` folder to where the dummy index.html was.

Hope this helps you now as much as it did for me!